# DataReader list C#/SQL Server Azure ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, pdf

I am working with ITextSharp a C# library for creating PDF's.  I have a column in a MSSQL Server table that contains uploaded file names of PDF's to be merged into one document.

```
     public void btnMerge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataReader rdr = null;
    string checkID = "1210";
    SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(sqlConnection);
    con2.Open();
    string sqlUserName2;
    sqlUserName2 = "SELECT AttachmentName FROM [Attachment] WHERE RequestId ='" + checkID + "'  ";
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sqlUserName2, con2);
    rdr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(rdr);
    List<PdfReader> readerList = new List<PdfReader>();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("http://azurewebsites.net/uploads/reports/" +
          Convert.ToString(row[0]));
        readerList.Add(pdfReader);
    }
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    //Get instance response output stream to write output file.
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
    string path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME").ToString() + "\\site\\wwwroot\\uploads\\reports\\";
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(path + Request.QueryString["id"] + "-" + Session["streetAddress"] + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
    document.Open();
    foreach (PdfReader reader in readerList)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
            document.Add(iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(page));
        }
    }
    document.Close();

    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + Request.QueryString["id"] + "-Final");
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
}
private void MergePDFs(string outPutFilePath, params string[] filesPath)
{
    List<PdfReader> readerList = new List<PdfReader>();
    foreach (string filePath in filesPath)
    {
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(filePath);
        readerList.Add(pdfReader);
    }

    //Define a new output document and its size, type
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    //Create blank output pdf file and get the stream to write on it.
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(outPutFilePath, FileMode.Create));
    document.Open();

    foreach (PdfReader reader in readerList)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
            document.Add(iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(page));
        }
    }
    document.Close();
}
```

I managed to use a DataReader and DataTable to temporarily Response.Write the values of each Row/Column in the returned results.  Now I need to build the "readerList" for ItextSharp to use to merge the files into a single PDF.  This is where I am stuck how do I replace the hard coded list in my code "pdfReader1 & pdfReader2" with the DataReader/DataTable results?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I edited the code above with the final working code for those who may need similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<PdfReader> readerList = new List<PdfReader>();
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
  PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("http://azurewebsites.net/uploads/reports/" + 
    Convert.ToString(row[0]));
  readerList.Add(pdfReader);
}
```

Comment: That looks perfect @Igor I am testing it now.